# Override CSS in AWS Amplify React UI

Tags: css, aws-amplify, css-variables, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I am using @aws-amplify/ui-react package for Auth.

I want to override a few CSS classes that come with it. The package heavily uses the CSS variables but I am not able to override them.

For example, I want to add the add border-radius to the button. I tried overriding the .button class in CSS files but it is not taking effect.

Following is how the DOM looks like.
[image]

I tried doing the following CSS but it does not seem to work.

```
amplify-button{
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```
.button{
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Any clue how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add the code that you are trying? It would be better if you can create a sandbox out of your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/

Comment: I added the code sample in the question.

Comment: It could be that code is overriding it. I can check that through a demo.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it is using a `shadow DOM`, you can't directly overwrite the elements/styles by changing the css, you'll need to inject the css into the shadow DOM

```js
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = '.the-class-name { property-name: my-value; }';
host.shadowRoot.appendChild( style );
// The host is the parent component in your DOM that contains
// the shadow DOM element.
const host = document.getElementById('host');
```

Another alternative is if the component you are using exposes `css path attribute` or `css variables` and then you could set them in your `style` element.

From the github library issues, they mention this problem, https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2471, with this example solution:

```css
@import '../css/app'

amplify-authenticator
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
    align-items: center
    height: 100vh
    font-family: 'Raleway', 'Open Sans', sans-serif
    min-width: 80vw
    padding: 10vmin

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 700px)
        margin: auto
        padding: 15vmin
        min-width: 100%

    --amplify-font-family: $typography-font-family
    --amplify-primary-color: #FA3336
```

Which would override the variables: `amplify-font-family` and `amplify-primary-color`.

Comment: What is host here?

Comment: It's the parent element that contains the shadow root. I'll update the answer